# Swift 3 - Horizontal Alignment of Buttons in UIAlertViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I want 3 buttons in `UIAlertViewController` Horizontally.But when i am trying to put 3 `UIAlertAction` it converts in `UIActionSheet`.

This is my code:-

```
   let alertv = UIAlertController.init(title: "Mesage", message: "Please Select one", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let beenT = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Create", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let viw = UIAlertAction.init(title: "View", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alertv.addAction(beenT)
    alertv.addAction(viw)
    alertv.addAction(cancel)
    present(alertv, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

`UIAlertView` I Want
  [image: UIalertView I Want]

Comment: can you show some UI

Comment: you want this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098700/how-to-rotate-uialertcontroller-in-swift or only you want to rotate UIAlertAction only

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik see my updated question

Comment: this one not possible in default UIAlertController if you want this use custom view

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how can i use it in custom view please help me